# TypeScript union function returning literal compiler error

Tags: typescript

Could someone walk me through what TypeScript is "thinking" in these scenarios involving return value type inference? I am guessing it has something to do with literal widening, but I'm unclear on exactly why one of these scenarios fails.

I have a type (**ContainingType**) that has a single member called *funcOrVal* (**FunctionOrValue**) which in turn is a union between a third type (**Value**) and a function returning a **Value** object.

```
type ContainingType =  {
    funcOrVal: FunctionOrValue;
};

type FunctionOrValue = Value | (() => Value);

type Value = "this" | "that" | number;
```

A. Now, if I create an instance of **ContainingType** and assign *funcOrVal* a **Value** directly, there are no problems.

```
const worksWithValue: ContainingType = {
    funcOrVal: "that"
};
```

B. However, assigning *funcOrVal* a function returning the same **Value** as before gives an error. This seems to happen only when assigning one of the string literal options.

```
const breaksWithLiteral: ContainingType = {
    funcOrVal: () => {
        return "that";
    }
};
```

C. Doing the same thing except assigning a number instead of one the string literal options works just fine.

```
const worksWithNumber: ContainingType = {
    funcOrVal: () => {
        return 123;
    }
};
```

D. I can make example B work by assigning the **Value** to an explicitly typed variable first.

```
const worksWithExplicitType: ContainingType = {
    funcOrVal: () => {
        const value: Value = "that";
        return value;
    }
};
```

E. Additionally, example B also works if I re-define **FunctionOrValue** to only allow functions.

```
type Function = () => Value;

type ContainingTypeFunctionOnly =  {
    func: Function;
};

const worksWithFunctionOnly: ContainingTypeFunctionOnly = {
    func: () => {
        return "that";
    }
};
```

### Question

What is about the combination of *funcOrVal* being a union type AND the return value being a literal type that causes the compiler to stop properly inferring the function's return type?

***edit:*** when trying to figure out the exact TypeScript version I was using (I have "Use latest available" selected for the project) a tsv -v showed my TypeScript version at 3.1.2. Since 3.3 was an option from the project menu, I toggled that and since then - even after switching back to "Use latest available" - I cannot reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's weird, I cannot reproduce the issue. I tried this code, it worked:

```js
type ContainingType =  {
  funcOrVal: FunctionOrValue;
};

type FunctionOrValue = Value | (() => Value);

type Value = "this" | "that" | number;

const breaksWithLiteral: ContainingType = {
  funcOrVal: () => {
    return "that";
  }
};
```

Can you give us your Typescript version and your tsconfig ?

Well, I guess that the function return type is inferred as `string` instead of `"that"`. If you've Typescript >=3.4 you can do this:

```js
  funcOrVal: () => {
    return "that" as const;
  }
```

Or simply (and I think better):

```js
  funcOrVal: (): Value => {
    return "that";
  }
```

But again, I can't reproduce the issue... hope I helped !

Comment: That actually helped a lot - in trying to figure out my TS version, I changed the project setting and even after changing it back, the error is gone.